# CSS and the jQuery contextMenu plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

This is a continuation of a [previous post](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/src/jquery.contextMenu.js), where I asked about how to define icons alongside the options: it is not resolved.

I am unable to display icons alongside the options.

And I think the problem lies in including the css file, with jQuery. For instance, [this resembling example](http://jsfiddle.net/x55Lr2wL/1/) does work. The only difference being that the stylesheet references exeternal icons on the web.

Minimum working exapmle, with seperate html,css and javascript files (jQuery includes the stylesheet file):

html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">       
<link href="http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/src/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/src/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="./markFeature.js" type="text/javascript"></script    
</head>
<body>
    <strong>right click me</strong>       
</body>
</html>
```

javascript/jQuery:

```
var Feature = {
    register_contextMenu: function(){
    Feature.addCSS();
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '*',
        //title : "Priotiteit",
        callback: function(key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
        "item_one": {name: "item-one", 
            icon: "green"},
        "item_two": {name: "item-two", 
            icon: "blue"},
        }
    });
    },

    addCSS: function(){
    $('head').append(
    '<link rel="stylesheet" href="Feature.css" type="text/css" />');
    }    
};
$(document).ready(markFeature.register_contextMenu);
```

CSS file:

```
.context-menu-item.icon {
  min-height: 18px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 4px 2px;
  }
.context-menu-item.icon-green {
    background-image: url("<absolutepath>/green.png");
    }
.context-menu-item.icon-blue {
    background-image: url("<absolutepath>/blue.png");
    }
```

I can not seem to get the icons dispalyed alongside the options.

The following example resembles my situation, with the difference that the css file references external icons on the web:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/x55Lr2wL/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

In an CSS file, one can only use relative paths.

The following works:

```
.context-menu-item.icon {
  min-height: 18px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 4px 2px;
  }
.context-menu-item.icon-green {
    background-image: url("<relativepath>/green.png");
    }
.context-menu-item.icon-blue {
    background-image: url("<relativepath>/blue.png");
    }
```